# How can I debug ELF binaries with IDA Pro for Windows?

Tags: windows, debugging, virtual-machine, elf, ida

I'm using IDA pro for windows and I can't debug ELF files (which seems normal). So I've been searching for a solution, and I found out that there was a way using linuxserver and a VM. I got a VM, I got the linuxserver executable, but I can't find out how to debug ELF files with IDA Windows.
Does anyone have a solution?

EDIT :

I needed to install gdbserver on my VM, launch it (gdbserver :55555 ./binary)
And debug with IDA pro using GDB remote server using intern network adress + port (55555 in this case).

Comment: Take a look to https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14363/debug-elf-executable

Comment: I finally found out how, thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Nark If you found out how, you should post an answer and accept it.